# How would one find the full changelog of the Vivaldi desktop web browser?

Tags: windows, browser, development, bug, vivaldi

I'm trying to find out if various old Vivaldi desktop web browser bugs I filed have been fixed.

Their RSS feed `https://vivaldi.com/feed/` can be parsed for new versions' changes and bug fixes. However, it only goes back to recently posted announcements.

I need the full history since day one. I have searched for this many times, spent a lot of time, but cannot find any such thing.

I even tried editing the URLs of existing (recent) webpages on their website which list changes/fixes for recent versions, but this did not work too far back, or very precisely.

This is so frustrating. I don't understand why every single company and software project seems to be so violently disorganized, at least publicly. They may have a perfect text file with all changes since the start internally, but I can't find this online/in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links are for downloading old versions of Vivaldi. The good thing is that the changelogs are listed with each version. The oldest version listed is 1.0344.37 (see image below).

- [Vivaldi on Windows](https://vivaldi.com/download/archive/?platform=win)
- [Vivaldi on Debian Linux](https://vivaldi.com/download/archive/?platform=linux)
- [Vivaldi on Mac](https://vivaldi.com/download/archive/?platform=mac)

> I even tried editing the URLs of existing (recent) webpages on their website which list changes/fixes for recent versions, but this did not work too far back, or very precisely.

You have not tried hard enough as I could find them very quickly!!!

> This is so frustrating. I don't understand why every single company and software project seems to be so violently disorganized, at least publicly. They may have a perfect text file with all changes since the start internally, but I can't find this online/in public.

Again, you have not tried hard enough!!!

[image]

Comment: My comment was deleted for no reason. What?

Comment: Release notes for snaphots can be found [in the blog](https://vivaldi.com/blog/desktop/snapshots/).